# Different devise models using same email id to register

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have created two different devise models and it's working fine . But the issue i am facing now is , that both the users are able to register with the same email id . I am looking to an easy fix for it but haven't been able to find one . Any suggestions on the same would be much welcome .

## VIEW CODE

```
<li>
<label>Email Address</label>
<%= f.email_field :email,:class => 'wh-txt-box' , :validate => { :presence => true }, :placeholder => 'Email address ' %>


</li>
```

Comment: Try adding a uniqueness validation for the email field `validates :email, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }`

Comment: I intend to use it for 2 different devise users like userA and userB , if i just put the same in both the models they will just search their own respective users email which kind of defeats the purpose .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple fix i suggest

```
class Usera

  validate :unique_email

  private
    def unique_email
      errors.add(:email, 'This Email is taken') unless Userb.where(email: self.email).blank?
  end
end


class Userb

  validate :unique_email

  private
    def unique_email
      errors.add(:email, 'This Email is taken') unless Usera.where(email: self.email).blank?
  end
end
```

Comment: I intend to use it for 2 different devise users like userA and userB

Comment: Well you can write the same function in UserA and UserB. I will edit the solution accordingly.

Comment: Yes but this code will ensure that either userA type or userB type won't be able to enter same email .It won't compare both the separate devise users email id .

Comment: UserA won't be able to register an account with any email id existing in its own model as well if that mail id exist in UserB. The validate will run the unique_email method and UserA registration fails if that mail id already exists in UserB

Comment: Also , wanted to display the message . I know it's there in the model code but it doesn't show "The email is taken " anywhere .

Comment: Can you paste your view code. It should mention that email is taken. The error is added to the attribute email.

Comment: Done , please check if there is anything else i need to add .

Comment: I don't know how you have done this. but we usually use a function to show the errors if there is any. `f.errors :email` should give the errors if any

Comment: Where should i mention this , can you please update your answer where you include that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Validation method for checking the Uniqueness of Email.

```
validate :unique_email

private

def unique_email
  user = User.where(email: email)

  # user.exists? insure you that this email is already present in 
  # your system. Now you need to validate that If it is a new record (new_record?)
  # then show error or at the time of update (read_attribute(:email) != self.email)
  # it will also validate that you are entering a unique email.

  if user.exists?
    if new_record? || read_attribute(:email) != self.email
      errors.add(:user, 'This email has already been taken.')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I intend to use it for 2 different devise users like userA and userB